# Where can I get pizza data

Tags: data-request

I'm studying the pizza market, especially in Utah, and I would like to know if there are any pizza data sources. Can some kind of sales tax data be used to study pizza? Is there a straight up pizza study that collected data? How creative do I have to get to find data? Or how much might I need to pay to have someone collect it?

Any data related to these things will be awesome: pizza input markets, pizza production, pizza demand, pizza labor, pizza firms, anything pizza and economics.

I'm not sure exactly what variables I'm after, I was just going to see which are out there first. I put in a request to Yelp.com to get access to their data sets, but it's only allowed for a few universities right now, not mine. We're on a wait list. Other than that, I'm kind of stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might not get you very far, but a start would be [Google Trends](https://www.google.co.uk/trends/explore#q=pizza+delivery,pizza+hut&geo=US):

[image: Google trends pizza data]

Comment: Wow! I would guess this could tell me about demand for pizza, or maybe competition between companies. Do you have any specific ideas, when it comes to econometric analysis?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't specific to Utah, but the pizza industry censuses on this page are detailed, if somewhat small in the number of survey responses:
http://www.pmq.com/Industry-News/

Comment: I saw some graphs and stuff, but I couldn't find the raw data, where is it?

Comment: Raw data is usually proprietary and/or not available for free. If you have a Bloomberg Terminal subscription (or have access to a library that has one) you can get raw data for the pizza market in Utah (and anywhere else in the world, if you like).

Comment: I do have access to a Bloomberg Terminal @rocinante. I'm super new to it though. What resource is there to guide me to pizza data? I've used the excel add-in to get data, so I assume I can use that again and work with the data from there. But how to get from point A (log on to bloomberg terminal) to point B (export data to excel using add in)?